# Ubuntu web server, how to hide filename in web address

Tags: webserver

I have a website that is called abc123.net and when I got to another page on the website, it takes me to abc123.net/newpage.php. How do I hide the file name of the page I am on? I do not want the newpage.php to be shown in the address bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't.

There's very good reasons for not hiding it. If a user bookmarks something, they expect to be taken to that exact page. If they view the history, they want to find the exact page. Not your front page, like they will with your scheme.

If you absolutely insist on doing it, you can use a full screen iframe. This requires editing your webpage, not configuring the webserver. Make `index.php` contain

```
<html><head>header</head><body>
<iframe src="/index2.php" width=100% height=100%> 
</iframe></body></html>
```

where index2.php is your real index.

Again, don't do this. It breaks the experience users expect. It may affect your SEO ranking as well. There's a reason why URLs are structured the way they are.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense,  I will probably not hide my filename.